# Dynamic key in bean:message in Struts 1.3

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I am working on a project which made use of an old (but nice) framework Struts 1.3, and I am trying to accomplish a simple task.

I have a bean containing a property, which is a key corresponding to a property file. I would like to use it for recall the appropriate translation.

Variable in property file

```
props.myprop.sample=This is my sample property
```

The property is in a bean passed to the jsp called for convenience AllProps which has a getter for the property, and this should be a pseudo code:

```
<bean:define id="sample" name="AllProps" property="sample" type="java.lang.String"/> // should result in sample = props.myprop.sample

<div><bean:message key="sample"/></div>
```

Which should output:

```
<div>This is my sample property</div>
```

But obviously result in a property not found, can you give me help on how to deal with this ?
I would like to stick as much as possible to Struts tag, then Jsp tag, and scriptlet as last resource.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straight from [the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#bean%3amessage):

```
<bean:message>
```

> Render an internationalized message string to the response.
>
> Retrieves an internationalized message for the specified locale, using
>   the specified message key, and write it to the output stream. Up to
>   five parametric replacements (such as "{0}") may be specified.
>
> The message key may be specified directly, using the key attribute, **or
>   indirectly, using the name and property attributes to obtain it from a
>   bean**.

(emphasis mine)

So, all you need is

```
<bean:message name="AllProps" property="sample"/>
```

Comment: I also found out that <bean:message key="<%= sample %>"/> solve the issue, but your solution is much more cleaner and Struts prone, and it works too.

Comment: The correct alternative syntax would be <bean:message key="employeuronss.eid.warning" arg0="<%=sample%>" />